# how to create "today", "yesterday", "3 days ago" using diffForHumans in laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-9, php-carbon

i need help to format diffForHumans to text :

> Today or Yesterday or 3 days ago etc.

i coded like this in my blade view

`{{ $data->created_at->diffForHumans() }}`

but the result just :

> 4 hours ago

can someone help me to make the code? thanks for your attention.

Comment: Actually, you might have already found it. Make lots of created_at records by seeding your database. So when you want 'yesterday' the created_at date must not be .... today. Make sure that the created_at is, for example '2022-01-01' and let's see what diffForHumans() makes of it

Comment: @UnderDog but how to change the text if the date is still today?

Comment: @FawwazSaputra I didn't understand your question. Do you need to localize the `today` and `yesterday` keywords?

Comment: @Saman i mean if created_at date still in today then the output is "Today" not 3 Hours ago, how to format it sir?

Comment: try ```diffInDays```, if it returns 0 then it's today, if it returned 1 then it's yesterday, otherwise you can just get the number returned and add to it "Days ago"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use

```
@if ($data->created_at->isToday())
    Today
@elseif($data->created_at->isYesterday())
    Yesterday
@else
    {{ $data->created_at->diffForHumans() }} Days Ago
@endif
```

Comment: is there a way to check a week? i want to check if a week has passed but it seems as the formatting this method uses, accounts up to 2 weeks and then it'll start printing the date, I want to print the date after the week passed.